# App closes immediately after launch, no error, no step-through in VS debugger

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

We received a bunch of new phones to use for testing en masse.  Currently, to deploy/install an app on a device i simply attach it via USB-cable to the dev computer and run the app from VisualStudio.

Well, things went totally unexpected with these ZTE Z798BL (Android 6.0.1):

1. I configure Developer Options on the phone (enable USB-debugging and Stay-awake).
2. I attach the USB-cable, the phone detects VStudio on the other end, asks for confirmation. Now the device is seen in VStudio's device drop-down - i pick it.
3. I 'Run' the app. VStudio compiles, packs, zip-aligns, and what not, then deploys the .apk.
4. VStudio switches into debug mode.
5. The phone loads the first activity, but no contents - just the header with the label.
6. A few seconds later activity disappears, VStudio switches back to edit mode .. **we're done**!

No exceptions, no errors, no "Unfortunately.." messages on the phone.  Trying again has no impact.  Setting breakpoints on the first lines of code have no impact.  Trying to step through (using [F11] instead of [F5]) has no impact - **the app just terminates before even reaching my code**.

Device-Log during launch attempt is filled with copious amounts of *shtuff* from all over:
[image: "How do they expect us to find anything in this sh*t?" - The Fifth Element]

Trying to filter using PID results in 10 lines that give absolutely no clue:
[image: only 10 entries for this process??]

On the whim i take a fresh Google Pixel phone, which has not yet been USB-connected to the dev computer.  Plug it in, enable USB-debugging, pick it in VisualStudio (still in the same session - no reboots, no restarts!), click 'Run', and after usual build actions visible in Output window .. voila: *here's the app running perfectly on Pixel for the very first time*!

---

Next thing i tried an ActivityLifecycle sample.  It did the same thing: "Activity A" title with no buttons flashes on the phone and disappears right away without any errors or exceptions.  I changed to:

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity AZ", MainLauncher = true)]
```

that resulted in title changing to "Activity A**Z**", but i still *cannot step through any code on ZTE*!

---

Without targeting any specifics the app runs on the following devices / Android versions:

- Google Nexus 4 (4.3, API:18)
- BLU Vivo 5 Mini (6.0, API:23)
- Samsung SM-T377V (7.1.1, API:25), updated from (6.0.1, API:23)
- Google Pixel (8.1.0, API:27)

*therefore, my guess is - this has something to do with the ZTE device itself*.
We got a bunch of 'em, so i take the next one .. **each one behaves the same way**!  WTF??

App's TargetPlatform is 7.1, MinimumVersion is 4.3, all 5 supported architectures are enabled.
VStudio - 15.5.4, .NET - 4.7.03056, Xamarin - 4.8.0.757, Xamarin.Android SDK - 8.1.3.0.

---

Today (2018-06-01) i paid more attention to Device Log output and found the following lines (of course many of these are *not* coming from my process!):

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
06-01 09:27:13.786  ZTE Z798BL  Info    1456    ActivityManager START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain} from uid 2000 (pid: 22859, caller: null) on display 0
06-01 09:27:13.786  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   22859   AndroidRuntime  Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-01 09:27:13.806  ZTE Z798BL  Verbose 1456    BoostFramework  BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@80107cc
06-01 09:27:13.806  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   jiangmin Set focused app to: AppWindowToken{5ed5159 token=Token{2da09d2 ActivityRecord{8434c5d u0 J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain t20}}} old focus=AppWindowToken{79d17c2 token=Token{9731c0d ActivityRecord{d06a6a4 u0 com.android.launcher3/.Launcher t6}}} moveFocusNow=true
06-01 09:27:13.806  ZTE Z798BL  Verbose 1456    BoostFramework  BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@173fdff
06-01 09:27:13.806  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   8462    Launcher_Launcher   Launcher onPause
06-01 09:27:13.806  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   22859   AndroidRuntime  Shutting down VM
06-01 09:27:13.816  ZTE Z798BL  Verbose 1456    BoostFramework  BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@c98aa15
06-01 09:27:13.826  ZTE Z798BL  Verbose 1456    BoostFramework  BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@81cd4b8
06-01 09:27:13.826  ZTE Z798BL  Info    1456    ActivityManager Start proc 22873:J7980ca.J7980ca/u0a91 for activity J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain
06-01 09:27:13.836  ZTE Z798BL  Info    22873   art Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-01 09:27:13.836  ZTE Z798BL  Info    22464   Finsky  [1] com.google.android.finsky.setup.ar.run(35): Detected restoreservicev2://recovery not needed, will not run
06-01 09:27:13.906  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   1456    Settings    return value in isSelf
06-01 09:27:13.906  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   1456    Settings    return value in isSelf
06-01 09:27:13.926  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__
06-01 09:27:13.926  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__`
06-01 09:27:13.926  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:13.926  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:13.926  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Using override path: /data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__
06-01 09:27:13.926  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:13.926  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:13.936  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:13.986  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22873   monodroid-debug Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29382,server=y,embedding=1
..
06-01 09:27:21.836  ZTE Z798BL  Info    1456    ActivityManager Killing 22873:J7980ca.J7980ca/u0a91 (adj 0): stop J7980ca.J7980ca
..
06-01 09:27:21.876  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   jiangmin Set focused app to: AppWindowToken{79d17c2 token=Token{9731c0d ActivityRecord{d06a6a4 u0 com.android.launcher3/.Launcher t6}}} old focus=AppWindowToken{5ed5159 token=Token{2da09d2 ActivityRecord{8434c5d u0 J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain t20}}} moveFocusNow=true
06-01 09:27:21.876  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    ActivityManager Spurious death for ProcessRecord{64106cf 0:J7980ca.J7980ca/u0a91}, curProc for 22873: null
06-01 09:27:21.866  ZTE Z798BL  Info    1456    ActivityManager Start proc 22915:J7980ca.J7980ca/u0a91 for activity J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain
  Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{8434c5d u0 J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain t20}
06-01 09:27:21.866  ZTE Z798BL  Verbose 1456    BoostFramework  BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@2f65b2e
06-01 09:27:21.856  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   1456    ActivityManager cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 22873
06-01 09:27:21.836  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   22904   AndroidRuntime  Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
06-01 09:27:21.836  ZTE Z798BL  Info    1456    ActivityManager Force stopping J7980ca.J7980ca appid=10091 user=0: from pid 22904
..
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   This window was lost: Window{cf842c9 u0 Starting J7980ca.J7980ca}
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   Frames: containing=[0,0][480,854] parent=[0,0][480,854]
    display=[0,0][480,854] overscan=[0,0][480,854]
    content=[0,36][480,854] visible=[0,36][480,854]
    decor=[0,36][480,854]
    outset=[0,0][0,0]
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mToken=AppWindowToken{5ed5159 token=Token{2da09d2 ActivityRecord{8434c5d u0 J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain t20}}}
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mSystemDecorRect=[0,36][480,854] last=[0,0][0,0]
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mSeq=0 mSystemUiVisibility=0x0
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   On display=0 Rebuild removed 3 windows but added 2
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mOwnerUid=1000 mShowToOwnerOnly=false package=J7980ca.J7980ca appop=NONE
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mExiting=false mRemoveOnExit=false mDestroying=false mRemoved=true
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mRootToken=AppWindowToken{5ed5159 token=Token{2da09d2 ActivityRecord{8434c5d u0 J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain t20}}}
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mConfiguration={1.0 310mcc260mnc en_US ldltr sw320dp w320dp h545dp 240dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.9}
06-01 09:27:21.956  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   1456    ActivityManager cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 22436
06-01 09:27:23.316  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   3648    Settings    return value in isSelf
 iswfc:false
06-01 09:27:23.316  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   3181    systemUI_BmpofEbubWjfx  mIsMmsApnDataState: false isWFCState:false
06-01 09:27:23.316  ZTE Z798BL  Error   3181    systemUI_QipofTubuvt    Failed to GetSimBySub local
06-01 09:27:23.316  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   3648    Settings    return value in isSelf
06-01 09:27:23.316  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   3648    Settings    return value in isSelf
06-01 09:27:22.466  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 8462    OpenGLRenderer  Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
06-01 09:27:22.466  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 8462    OpenGLRenderer  Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
06-01 09:27:22.086  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   3648    Settings    return value in isSelf
06-01 09:27:22.016  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid-debug Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29382,server=y,embedding=1
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Creating public update directory: `/data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__`
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/../legacy/Android/data/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/J7980ca.J7980ca-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
06-01 09:27:22.006  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 22915   monodroid   Using override path: /data/user/0/J7980ca.J7980ca/files/.__override__
06-01 09:27:21.986  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   1456    Settings    return value in isSelf
06-01 09:27:21.986  ZTE Z798BL  Debug   1456    Settings    return value in isSelf
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   WindowStateAnimator{102a206 Starting J7980ca.J7980ca}:
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mViewVisibility=0x0 mHaveFrame=true mObscured=false
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mAppToken=AppWindowToken{5ed5159 token=Token{2da09d2 ActivityRecord{8434c5d u0 J7980ca.J7980ca/md54e704423a01db64492900da8de435cc0.ActMain t20}}}
06-01 09:27:21.976  ZTE Z798BL  Warning 1456    WindowManager   mHasSurface=false mShownFrame=[0.0,0.0][480.0,854.0] isReadyForDisplay()=false
..
```

I only discovered these searching for 'J7980ca' - project name.  I'll be happy to include full captures, but they take up too much space.  Is there a way to upload text files similar to how images are done?

What's weird is that after a *spurious death* (even though there's no reference to original PID?!) it looks as if the app is being re-loaded again?  I paused logging ~15 sec after VStudio stopped debugging, there are no more entries explicitly mentioning my project or its classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, accidentally i just found that once ZTE is unhooked from USB-cable, the app loads properly. Plugging the phone back and attempting to run the app from VStudio still results in "Spurious death for Process.." without any useful clues. *But unplugging again seems to restore app's ability to run*.

My only explanation is **presence of the debugger is somehow unfavored**?!

But i'll take that, as it allows me deploying next dev-build to the phone and running it unplugged.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a virtual test using the emulator and create an image of the phone using this technique: [Run a full android phone rom on the Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165570/run-a-full-android-phone-rom-on-the-android-emulator)

That way you can "eleminate" the ZTE hardware and probably do a better debug using the emulator image.

Note: After upgrading to Visual Studio 15.7.3 and updated Xamarin my app did not start in the emulator anymore. I had to manually remove "Mono shared runtime" and "Xamarin.Android API-xx Support" and last my installed app. Did a total rebuild of the app and a new deploy, it worked fined after that.

Also suggested to try a deploy without the shared runtime, remove the check in Properties -> Android Options -> Use shared runtime

If you're still stuck; go to the beach and check if the ZTEs floats ;)

Comment: After trying initially to run the very first "Hello, world" app in the emulator, and then seeing how efficient is deployment and even debugging on a physical device, i swore to never ever invoke the emulator again.  Still it seems to me, **that^** won't prove that the problem *is* (or *is not*) specifically ZTE hardware.  
Did try cleaning, deleting /bin and /obj folders, and rebuilding - no dice.  
Updating VS/Xamarin/SDKs may be needed, but i hate touching setups that work for everything else.

Comment: My point is that Android isn't stock on every device. Maybe ZTE developers has tinkered with the Android installation in any way. By making a one-to-one copy into an emulator it will eliminate error with software on the ZTE and your back to hardware error.